# I'm trying to install the build-essential package but it fails at installing g++ and libc6

Tags: 18.04, package-management, compiling

**First off,
i'm very new to linux, using it for whole 2 days now.**

**I'm trying to build an app with QT Creator but I can't use the c++ compiler since it doesn't want to Install.**

I Tried installing the **build-essential** package to use QT properly, these packages installed without any problems:

1. **dpkg-dev**
2. **gcc**
3. **make**

Though **libc6** and **g++** didn't so I tried installing all their dependencies and it throws me into a weird loop where it says that **libc6** is installed.

This is the order I tried to install the package:

````
:~$ sudo apt install build-essential
 Reading package lists... Done
Building dependency tree       
Reading state information... Done
Some packages could not be installed. This may mean that you have
requested an impossible situation or if you are using the unstable
distribution that some required packages have not yet been created
or been moved out of Incoming.
The following information may help to resolve the situation:

The following packages have unmet dependencies:
 build-essential : Depends: libc6-dev but it is not going to be installed or
                            libc-dev
                   Depends: g++ (>= 4:7.2) but it is not going to be installed
E: Unable to correct problems, you have held broken packages.```




:~$ sudo apt install libc-dev
Reading package lists... Done
Building dependency tree       
Reading state information... Done
Note, selecting 'libc6-dev' instead of 'libc-dev'
Some packages could not be installed. This may mean that you have
requested an impossible situation or if you are using the unstable
distribution that some required packages have not yet been created
or been moved out of Incoming.
The following information may help to resolve the situation:

The following packages have unmet dependencies:
 libc6-dev : Depends: libc6 (= 2.27-3ubuntu1) but 2.28-0ubuntu1+zorin4 is to be installed
             Depends: libc-dev-bin (= 2.27-3ubuntu1)
E: Unable to correct problems, you have held broken packages.






:~$ sudo apt install libc6
Reading package lists... Done
Building dependency tree       
Reading state information... Done
libc6 is already the newest version (2.28-0ubuntu1+zorin4).
0 upgraded, 0 newly installed, 0 to remove and 0 not upgraded.
````

Now bear In mind that I'm a total noob at linux, so any help would be appreciated.

Comment: Are you using Ubuntu - or Zorin?

Comment: Do you have any ppas installed?

Comment: I'm using Zorin 15

Comment: It's built on Ubuntu 18.04 though

Comment: The install command is `sudo apt update && sudo apt install build-essential`

Comment: Still gives me the dependencies 'missing' : libc6-dev libc-dev

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Unable to correct problems, you have held broken packages](https://askubuntu.com/questions/223237/unable-to-correct-problems-you-have-held-broken-packages)